# Where to find the select html tag for countries on the checkout page in Magento 1.8

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

Where can I the html **select** tag for countries on the checkout page?

```
<div class="field form-group">
       <label for="billing:country_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
       <div class="input-box">
          <?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
       </div>
</div>
```

with this `$this->getCountryHtmlSelect('billing')`, it returns the html select tag below,

```
<select name="billing[country_id]" id="billing:country_id" class="validate-select" title="Country" >
<option value="" > </option>
<option value="AF" >Afghanistan</option><option value="AL" >Albania</option>
<option value="DZ" >Algeria</option>
...
```

But I need to **add a class name** to the `select` tag,

```
class="form-control validate-select"
```

But where can I find this `select` tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For add new class in select ...you need to flow below steps:

Step:copy `app\code\core\Mage\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Abstract.php`
     to `app\code\local\Mage\Checkout\Block\Onepage\Abstract.php`

Here you have find the function `getCountryHtmlSelect($type)`

COde

```
    $select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
                ->setName($type.'[country_id]')
                ->setId($type.':country_id')
                ->setTitle(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Country'))
                ->setClass('validate-select')
        ->setValue($countryId)
```

Change to  and i have added a new class  `mynewclass`..

```
if($type=='billing')
{
$select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
            ->setName($type.'[country_id]')
            ->setId($type.':country_id')
            ->setTitle(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Country'))
            ->setClass('validate-select mynewclass')
            ->setValue($countryId)
}else{
$select = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/html_select')
            ->setName($type.'[country_id]')
            ->setId($type.':country_id')
            ->setTitle(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Country'))
            ->setClass('validate-select')
            ->setValue($countryId)
}
```

Comment: is there any way to add a JavaScript function for onchange in the country select